# Web3.eth.getAccounts() return undefined

Tags: javascript, solidity, web3js, metamask

I am trying to create an "mint button" by using the Web3.js libraries.
I managed to make the website open metamask for the user to connect, but unfortunately it doesn't seems to "see" the user address.
Using web3.eth.getAccounts() was suppose to catch the address and return something like 0x1533165446498754 but instead it returned undefined:

Full code:

```
import {myABI} from './myABI.js';   // Connect to the Ethereum network using Web3.js

var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://eth-goerli.g.alchemy.com/v2/xxxxxx-"));

var contractAddress = "0xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
var contractABI = myABI;

var myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(contractABI, contractAddress);

if (typeof window.ethereum !== 'undefined') {
  console.log('Metamask is installed!');
}

// Request account access if needed
await window.ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });

var accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
var account = accounts[0];

function delay(time) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time));
}
await delay(10000)


await console.log('Connected to Metamask account:', account);
console.log(account)

// Define the function you want to execute from the contract
var myFunction = myContract.methods.mint(1000000000000000);


web3.eth.defaultAccount = account;
// Create an HTML button
const myButton = document.querySelector("#myButton");


// Add an event listener to the button
myButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  // Execute the function defined above
  myFunction.send({from: web3.eth.defaultAccount});
});
```

instead of using `var accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();`

I have tried `var accounts = await web3.eth.requestAccounts();` but i get error

> Uncaught Error: Returned error: Unsupported method: eth_requestAccounts

I have tried to delete the [0] in `var account = accounts[0];` and it returned an array[] as an address and is unusable

I want  the function to return metamask wallet address im connected to

Comment: You must install the [metamask](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/metamask/nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn) add-on in your browser and signin

Comment: make sure the browser is connected to the metamask. previously created a `connect to metamask` button before making a `send` transaction

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So basically looking at alchemy's docs, the `web3.eth.getAccounts()` with alchemy provider return the following `Returns a list of addresses owned by client. Since Alchemy does not store keys, this will always return empty.` this is why it return as either undefined or [].

I have change the provider to `var web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);` ,
and it working so far.

I dont know the exact security implication of using Metamask as an provider instead of alchemy or infuria therefore i wouldnt considered it as a proper solution , use with care